# Pulseaudio-Streaming: Videos hang

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, vlc, streaming

I've got a problem with pulseaudio streaming and videos.

The configuration:

Server with soundsystem:

```
Mini-PC with Intel Celeron J1900, 5.1 Audio and GBit Ethernet running Xubuntu 14.04.
```

Client which streams:

```
Tried 2 Lenovo laptops (Thinkpad T510, IdeaPad Z560) with Fedora 20
```

When playing music on the client everything works fine.
But when I play a video (totem, vlc, mplayer), the video playback on the client hangs after about 1 second and after some more both video and audio hangs.

Does anyone else have this problem? Or a solution for this?